# There is a problem connecting my Android application to MySQL

Tags: android, mysql, kotlin, phpmyadmin, localserver

I'm new to creating Android applications,I write code in Kotlin and I need your help.

I want to connect my Android application to my local server which is located on the MySQl computer. I already wrote the code and thought that it would work one hundred percent but nothing worked. I need to for example, my user could register and this data was sent to the server and then I could easily log into this account using this data.

I already have a website that is already connected to this local server and to the database and everything works fine.

**This is file "Dbhelper"**

```
package com.example.myapplication

import java.sql.Connection
import java.sql.DriverManager
import java.sql.ResultSet
import java.sql.SQLException

class Dbhelper(private val url: String, private val user: 
String, private val password: String) {
init {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")
    } catch (e: ClassNotFoundException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}

fun connect(): Connection? {
    try {
        return DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password)
    } catch (e: SQLException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return null
}

fun isUserExists(login: String, email: String): Boolean {
    connect()?.use { connection ->
        val query = "SELECT * FROM appmovie_users WHERE login = ? OR email = ?"
        val preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query)
        preparedStatement.setString(1, login)
        preparedStatement.setString(2, email)
        val resultSet: ResultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery()
        return resultSet.next()
    }
    return false
}

fun addUser(login: String, email: String, password: String): Boolean {
    connect()?.use { connection ->
        val query = "INSERT INTO appmovie_users (login, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
        val preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query)
        preparedStatement.setString(1, login)
        preparedStatement.setString(2, email)
        preparedStatement.setString(3, password)
        val rowsAffected = preparedStatement.executeUpdate()
        return rowsAffected > 0
    }
    return false
}
```

}

**This is file "RegistrationActivity.kt"**

```
package com.example.myapplication 
                                                          
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider

class RegistrationActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var viewModel: RegistrationViewModel

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.registration)

    val userLogin = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.user_login)
    val userEmail = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.user_email)
    val userPass = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.user_pass)
    val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_reg)
    val linkToAuth = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.link_to_auth)
    val logoName = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.logoName)

    val dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database-users-movieapp"
    val dbUser = "root"
    val dbPassword = ""

    val dbHelper = Dbhelper(dbUrl, dbUser, dbPassword)

    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[RegistrationViewModel::class.java]

    button.setOnClickListener {
        val login = userLogin.text.toString().trim()
        val email = userEmail.text.toString().trim()
        val pass = userPass.text.toString().trim()

        if (login == "" || email == "" || pass == "") {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Not all fields are filled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        } else {
            if (dbHelper.isUserExists(login, email)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "User with the same login or email already exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            } else {
                viewModel.registerUser(login, email, pass)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}
**This is file "RegistrationViewModel"**

```
package com.example.myapplication

import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class RegistrationViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database- 
 users-movieapp"
private val DB_USER = "root"
private val DB_PASSWORD = ""

private val databaseHelper = Dbhelper(DB_URL, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD)

val registrationResult = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()

fun registerUser(login: String, email: String, password: String) {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val isRegistrationSuccessful = databaseHelper.addUser(login, email, password)
        registrationResult.postValue(isRegistrationSuccessful)
    }
}
```

}

I tried quite a lot of things but nothing helps, still when I enter the registration data and click on the button to submit, nothing happens

Comment: Hello, we need some code to see what's wrong with your code, otherwise is hard to determinate the issue.

Comment: I added part of the code,do you need more?

Comment: It's not the right way to do this. You have to develop API, webservices on your server

Comment: This is a localserver how I can do that?